# Python requests package script error

Tags: python

I am getting an error with this script when I run it
Also I should mention I just started learning Python

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json
import sys
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue

numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
builderThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
startTime = time.time()
numberOfSockets = 0
concurrent = 25
urls = []
urlsUsed = []

def getURL(): # Get tokens
    output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/ispazzcraft", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter

def build(): # Builds a set of tokens, aka viewers
    global numberOfSockets
    global numberOfViewers
    while True:
        if numberOfSockets < numberOfViewers:
            numberOfSockets += 1
            print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
            urls.append(getURL())

def view(): # Opens connections to send views
    global numberOfSockets
    while True:
        url=q.get()
        requests.head(url)
        if (url in urlsUsed):
            urls.remove(url)
            urlsUsed.remove(url)
            numberOfSockets -= 1
        else:
            urlsUsed.append(url)
        q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, builderThreads):
        threading.Thread(target = build).start()

    while True:
        while (numberOfViewers != numberOfSockets): # Wait until sockets are built
            time.sleep(1)

        q=Queue(concurrent*2)
        for i in range(concurrent):
            try:
                t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                t.daemon=True
                t.start()
            except:
                print 'thread error'
        try:
            for url in urls:
                print url
                q.put(url.strip())
                q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(1)
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Someone else said they fixed it by installing requests package and I did but I am still getting this error
Also I looked and I do have the latest version of the requests package

Comment: sys.argv is a list of arguments submitted via the command line. If you're getting this error it means you didn't supply enough arguments. You need to run this script from the command line, as so: `python script.py 12 19` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide 2 command line parameters (numbers) to use this script:

```
numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
builderThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
```

for example, if name of script is test.py:

```
test.py 1 2
```